# DaggerApplicationComponent not generated in my code?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, rx-android, dagger

DaggerApplicationComponent is not generated in my code, I am learning Dagger for android and facing this issue. Below my project files.

https://github.com/SK010101/AdvanceAndroidTutorial

//        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()

//                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
//                .build();

this thing not generated.

I have tried all clean and rebuild project.
Also tried Invalidate Caches/Restart.
Please help anyone))

Comment: Usually dagger says what is wrong in gradle console output. We cant tell unless we see more of your code and the console output

Answer (score 1):

inside dependencies block, add these lines:

```
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'

     compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
     implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Inside android block of build.gradle,

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

At the top of the build.gradle, Do this in exactly below order.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Finally, You need to enable  **"Annotation processor"** from *File>Other Settings>Settings for New Projects>search"Annotation processor"*

After this, do from Menu *Build > Rebuild*. Done!

Answer (score 0):

My Bug solved after Build run on emulator))